# core data update question

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have the following class in core data

```
@class Studies;

@interface Seriese :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * SereiesID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Series_Description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *Series_Date;

@end
```

how to update the Series_Description field please

best regards

Answer (score 2):

You update it just as you would any other property, by assigning to the property or by calling the `setSeries_Description:` method. Then make sure to call `save:` on the corresponding NSManagedObjectContext at some point so the changes are actually saved to the data store.